# Two Rails Applications communicating via API on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Two applications are meant to communicate with each other via API.
Both applications can be the server and client depending on given functions.

Aside from stubbing tests within each application, matters such as cron jobs require a functioning environment where the two actually communicate - to observe, test.

How can this be accomplished without a 3rd-level domain or ip address - essentially constrianed to localhost ?  Different loaclhost ports ? How can this be run properly?

Comment: Take a look at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails-server.
Try to run `rails server -p 3001` on one of the apps.

Comment: What is your question? There is no difference really between using HTTP to communicate on a local network and between different servers. "Different loaclhost ports?" - yes of course. You can't start two Rails servers on the same port. That goes for pretty much any type of HTTP server or service in general.